# Can't set Typography in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I use the default Typography in Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-beta08. But logcat gave me the error info like this:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method copy-H99Ercs$default(Landroidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle;JJLandroidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontWeight;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontStyle;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontSynthesis;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;JLandroidx/compose/ui/text/style/BaselineShift;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextGeometricTransform;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/intl/LocaleList;JLandroidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextDecoration;Landroidx/compose/ui/graphics/Shadow;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextAlign;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextDirection;JLandroidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextIndent;ILjava/lang/Object;)Landroidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle; in class Landroidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle' appears in /data/app/~~dzGPwRcTH3NcPitRFMz-4g==/cn.phakel.fighting-5iN5DgNNOwwUjTIkZ-2A6Q==/base.apk)
    at androidx.compose.material.TypographyKt.withDefaultFontFamily(Typography.kt:284)
    at androidx.compose.material.TypographyKt.access$withDefaultFontFamily(Typography.kt:1)
    at androidx.compose.material.Typography.<init>(Typography.kt:186)
    at androidx.compose.material.Typography.<init>(Typography.kt:118)
    at cn.phakel.fighting.ui.theme.TypeKt.<clinit>(Type.kt:10)
    at cn.phakel.fighting.ui.theme.TypeKt.getTypography(Type.kt:10)
    at cn.phakel.fighting.ui.theme.ThemeKt.FightingTheme(Theme.kt:36)
    at cn.phakel.fighting.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:19)
    at cn.phakel.fighting.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:18)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
```

This is my Type.kt:

```
val Typography = Typography(
    body1 = TextStyle(
            fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
            fontSize = 16.sp
    ),
    button = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W500,
        fontSize = 14.sp
    ),
    caption = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 12.sp
    )
)
```

Theme.kt:

```
@Composable
fun FightingTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable() () -> Unit) {
val colors = if (darkTheme) {
    DarkColorPalette
} else {
    LightColorPalette
}

MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
)
}
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
@ExperimentalPagerApi
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        FightingTheme {
            Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                Home(navController = navController)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Gradle setting for Project:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    compose_version = '1.0.0-beta08'
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-beta04'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

Gradle setting for module:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "cn.phakel.fighting"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
    useIR = true
}
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.32'
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-beta01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.11.1'
    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-coil:0.11.0'
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-okhttp:10.11'
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-gson:10.11'
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-slf4j:10.11'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha03'
}
```

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
kotlin.code.style=official
```

settings.gradle:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
}
}
rootProject.name = "Fighting"
include ':app'
```

I think that it may be caused by the wrong version. But I don't know how to solve this. Please tell me how to fix this if you know.

Comment: Could you post your `MainActivity` also?

Comment: And also the gradle.properties please

Comment: You say you are using `dev08` but in the code you have `compose_version = '1.0.0-beta08'`

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I edited again, and I also added settings.gradle

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem and I think they just fixed it.

```
ext {
    compose_version = '1.0.0-beta09'
}
```

Comment: Same! You're the best

Answer (score 1):

In your Gradle file, app level, inside Compose options block, remove the Kotlin compiler line. Also, update to compose beta09 by changing the compose version in the project level Gradle file

Answer (score 0):

What i would recommend just for safety measure, as in response above, upgrade your compose dependencies to the latest versions, or if just upgrade your `implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:<latestVersion>` dependency.